# Hibernating Rhinos Profiler Column Type Mismatch Warning

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, profiler

When i run the entity framework profiler i get lost of Column Type mismatch errors which apparently can affect performance
http://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf/learn/alert/ColumnTypeMismatch

So i tried to match my entity up to the database using attributes but i still get the warning.

```
[Key, Required, Column(TypeName = "nvarchar"), StringLength(25)]
public virtual string UserLoginName { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar"), StringLength(50)]
public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar"), StringLength(50)]
public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

[Column("UserType", TypeName = "int")]
public virtual CompanyType? CompanyType { get; set; } // this is a ENUM nut maps to a int is this correct to map to int?

public virtual ICollection<Permits> Permits { get; set; } // navigation property so no attributes?

[Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
public virtual DateTime? DOB{ get; set; } // is it correct to map datetime to Datetime2?

[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
public virtual string Notes { get; set; }
```

Comment: would help if you posted the database schema